# object reference not found Component.InvokeAsync

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am calling partial view as Async i found solution given below but still problem @await not found assemblies or reference  how i can use in My _PartialView.cshtml.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("YourComponent")
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: yes Asp.net Core with MVC razor